# Probability generating function of negative binomial distribution proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification, normal-distribution, expectation

So the textbooks says:

Let $X_r$ ~ $NB(r,p)$. We could use the probability generating functions to prove that

$G_{X_r} (s) = (\frac{ps}{1-(1-p)s})^r$:

Let $X$ have the Geometric distribution with success probability $0 < p < 1$.

Then $pk := (1 − p) ^{k−1} p$ and $G_s(s) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty  $ $(1-p)^{k-1}ps^k$  = ps$\sum_{k=0}^\infty  $$((1-p)s)^k$ = $ps/(1-(1-p)s)$

Furthermore, for a positive integer $r > 0$, let $X$ have the Negative Binomial distribution with parameter $(p,r)$.

Then, for $X_1, . . . , X_r$ i.i.d. Geometric$(p)$ random variables,

$G_{X_r} (s) = G_{X_1, . . . , X_r}$= $(\frac{ps}{1-(1-p)s})^r$

But it also says: We could use conditional expectation to find a recurrence relation between $G_{X_r} (s)$and $G_{X_{r-1}} (s)$ to prove.

But I don't see how to use the conditional expectation to prove the problem?

Comment: Welcome. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use conditional expectation as follows:

\begin{align}
G_{X_r}(s) &= E\left(s^{X_r}\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\text{$n^{th}$ trial is first success}) E\left(s^{X_r} \mid \text{$n^{th}$ trial is first success}\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{n-1}p E\left(s^{n+X_{r-1}}\right) \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{where $q=1-p$} \\
&= E\left(s^{X_{r-1}}\right) \dfrac{p}{q} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (qs)^n \\
&= G_{X_{r-1}}(s) \dfrac{p}{q} \dfrac{qs}{1-qs} \\
&= \dfrac{ps}{1-qs} G_{X_{r-1}}(s) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{is the recurrence relation} \\
&= \left(\dfrac{ps}{1-qs}\right)^{r-1} G_{X_{1}}(s) \\
&= \left(\dfrac{ps}{1-qs}\right)^{r} \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{since $X_1\sim$ Geom$(p)$ and has pgf $\dfrac{ps}{1-qs}$}. \\
\end{align}